# JavaScript in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition

Tags: javascript, intellij-plugin

Well, I would like to have JavaScript running in my IDE. The question is: how to run JavaScript in Intellij IDEA Community Edition? It is possible or just for the ultimate version? (cause I can't find the javascript and typescripts plugins)....I liked the Jetbrains IDE, but seems that i should go to try VStudio....

I try installing the plugins, but i can't see them on the plugin list. I also read about WebStorm, but I dont want to have another software, I would like to have all the languages in the same IDE

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript isn't supported in Intellij IDEA Community Edition. From [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javascript-specific-guidelines.html):

> Javascript and TypeScript -  The plugin is available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, where it is enabled by default.

But there is [WebCalm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/21826-webcalm-javascript-and-css) - a 3-rd party plugin (I'm the developer) that adds JavaScript/CSS support for free.